# Color inconsistent when exporting to PDF from InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, tables, color-match

Whenever I export these tables from InDesign to a PFD file, shaded rows appear as different colors, even though they are exactly matching in the original file. Is there are way to fix this? Color conversion isn't selected when exporting.[image: color doesn't match]

Sorry, I didn't provide enough info. I'm new to both InDesign and StackExchange. I did a couple of screen caps for my export settings that may help clarify what I'm doing wrong. I am viewing mismatched colors in the exported file with Adobe Acrobat DC. The PDF appears fine when viewed in DropBox (where I upload it to,) but downloading it to Acrobat throws the green color off. It's RGB defined and will only be seen online by the client. [][2 PDF export general settings][image]

Comment: Which colors exactly do you mean? The two greens that are obviously different or the fact that the grays in the top table are slightly different from each other? Have you checked that all colors that should be the same are in fact using the same swatch? How are the colors defined? Could there be a mix of RGB and CMYK? Have you perhaps enabled *Alternating Fills* in the *Table Options*? Which PDF viewer do you use? How does the PDF look in Acrobat?

Comment: RGB or CMYK? What are your export settings? What is InDesign's blend space set to? You honestly haven't provided any information in order to help.

Comment: If color conversion isn't selected then there's not much to expect the colors would look right. Anyway not enough info to debug. WHat source color space do you have what output settings do you have. where do you get the output image etc etc.

Comment: @Wolff Yes, it is the green that's the problem They are using the same swatch. It's RGB since the client will be viewing it online. There are not alternating fills in the table which I place from Word. I'm using Adobe Acrobat DC. Please forgive my ignorance. I am a novice InDesign user. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @JohnLee, really hard to say exactly what's going on without examining the file (which is out of scope for this site). One tip I can give you though (which *might* work as a workaround to the issue) is to set *Save as type* to *Adobe PDF (Interactive)* instead of *Adobe PDF (Print)* when exporting. It's a simpler export interface and exports PDFs specifically made to be viewed on screen. They render a little nicer on screen and are always converted to sRGB.

Comment: Thanks @Wolff I will try that. Ultimately, the client will print a copy, but he shares with his clients online first. Hopefully the print colors will actually match, but they aren't too concerned. I am pickier than that are.